# Fatal error: Declaration of AdminUserRole::getAccessibleEmployeeIds() must be compatible with that of AbstractUserRole::getAccessibleEmployeeIds()

Tags: php, symfony, orangehrm

I have a web application written in PHP using Symfony, I moved it from local computer to  a remote server. And when I try to login I got the error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of AdminUserRole::getAccessibleEmployeeIds() must be compatible with that of AbstractUserRole::getAccessibleEmployeeIds()

AdminUserRole class

```
class AdminUserRole extends AbstractUserRole {

public function getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation = null, $returnType = null, $requiredPermissions = array()) {

    return $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployeeIdList(false);
}

public function getAccessibleEmployeePropertyList($properties, $orderField, $orderBy, $requiredPermissions = array()) {

    return $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployeePropertyList($properties, $orderField, $orderBy, false);
}

public function getAccessibleEmployees($operation = null, $returnType = null, $requiredPermissions = array()) {

    $employees = $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployeeList('empNumber', 'ASC', true);

    $employeesWithIds = array();

    foreach ($employees as $employee) {
        $employeesWithIds[$employee->getEmpNumber()] = $employee;
    }

    return $employeesWithIds;
}

public function getAccessibleLocationIds($operation, $returnType) {

    $locations = $this->getLocationService()->getLocationList();

    $ids = array();

    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        $ids[] = $location->getId();
    }

    return $ids;
}

public function getAccessibleOperationalCountryIds($operation, $returnType) {

    $operationalCountries = $this->getOperationalCountryService()->getOperationalCountryList();

    $ids = array();

    foreach ($operationalCountries as $country) {
        $ids[] = $country->getId();
    }

    return $ids;
}

public function getAccessibleSystemUserIds($operation, $returnType) {

    return $this->getSystemUserService()->getSystemUserIdList();
}

public function getAccessibleUserRoleIds($operation, $returnType) {

    $userRoles = $this->getSystemUserService()->getAssignableUserRoles();

    $ids = array();

    foreach ($userRoles as $role) {
        $ids[] = $role->getId();
    }

    return $ids;
}
```

}

And my Abstract class

```
abstract class AbstractUserRole {

protected $employeeService;
protected $systemUserService;
protected $operationalCountryService;
protected $locationService;

protected $userRoleManager;

protected $roleName;

public function __construct($roleName, $userRoleManager) {
    $this->userRoleManager = $userRoleManager;
    $this->roleName = $roleName;        
}

public function getSystemUserService() {
    if (empty($this->systemUserService)) {
        $this->systemUserService = new SystemUserService();
    }
    return $this->systemUserService;
}

public function setSystemUserService($systemUserService) {
    $this->systemUserService = $systemUserService;
}

public function getEmployeeService() {

    if (empty($this->employeeService)) {
        $this->employeeService = new EmployeeService();
    }
    return $this->employeeService;
}

public function setEmployeeService($employeeService) {
    $this->employeeService = $employeeService;
}

public function getLocationService() {
    if (empty($this->locationService)) {
        $this->locationService = new LocationService();
    }
    return $this->locationService;
}

public function setLocationService($locationService) {
    $this->locationService = $locationService;
}

public function getOperationalCountryService() {
    if (empty($this->operationalCountryService)) {
        $this->operationalCountryService = new OperationalCountryService();
    }
    return $this->operationalCountryService;
}

public function setOperationalCountryService($operationalCountryService) {
    $this->operationalCountryService = $operationalCountryService;
}

public function getAccessibleEntities($entityType, $operation = null, $returnType = null, $requiredPermissions = array()) {

    switch ($entityType) {
        case 'Employee':
            $entities = $this->getAccessibleEmployees($operation, $returnType, $requiredPermissions);
            break;
    }
    return $entities;
}

public function getAccessibleEntityProperties($entityType, $properties = array(), $orderField = null, $orderBy = null, $requiredPermissions = array()) {

    switch ($entityType) {
        case 'Employee':
            $propertyList = $this->getAccessibleEmployeePropertyList($properties, $orderField, $orderBy, $requiredPermissions);
            break;
    }
    return $propertyList;
}

public function getAccessibleEntityIds($entityType, $operation = null, $returnType = null, $requiredPermissions = array()) {   

    switch ($entityType) {
        case 'Employee':
            $ids = $this->getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation, $returnType, $requiredPermissions);                
            break;
        case 'SystemUser':
            $ids = $this->getAccessibleSystemUserIds($operation, $returnType);
            break;
        case 'OperationalCountry':
            $ids = $this->getAccessibleOperationalCountryIds($operation, $returnType);
            break;
        case 'UserRole':
            $ids = $this->getAccessibleUserRoleIds($operation, $returnType);
            break;
        case 'Location':
            $ids = $this->getAccessibleLocationIds($operation, $returnType);
            break;
    }
    return $ids;
}

public abstract function getAccessibleEmployees($operation = null, $returnType = null, $requiredPermissions = array());

public abstract function getAccessibleEmployeePropertyList($properties, $orderField, $orderBy, $requiredPermissions = array());

public abstract function getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation, $returnType, $requiredPermissions = array());

public abstract function getAccessibleSystemUserIds($operation, $returnType);

public abstract function getAccessibleOperationalCountryIds($operation, $returnType);

public abstract function getAccessibleUserRoleIds($operation, $returnType);

public abstract function getAccessibleLocationIds($operation, $returnType);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Well, the two function signatures are not compatible.

```
abstract public function getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation, $returnType, $requiredPermissions = array());
         public function getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation = null, $returnType = null, $requiredPermissions = array()) {
```

The `abstract` function requires at least two arguments, while your implementation can be called without arguments. That's not the same signature. Remove the `null` default values.

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration is

```
public abstract function getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation, $returnType, $requiredPermissions = array());
```

but the actual implementation is

```
public function getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation = null, $returnType = null, $requiredPermissions = array());
```

As you can see, the original declaration requires at least 2 parameters, but your implementation suddenly says that none are required.

You probably have strict mode enabled in PHP on the server or just have a newer version installed with stricter rules set, that enforce implementations to be exactly like the declarations.

Just change the code in `AdminUserRole.php` to

```
public function getAccessibleEmployeeIds($operation, $returnType, $requiredPermissions = array())
{
    return $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployeeIdList(false);
}
```

and you'll be fine.